# C typedef and pointers to struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

If I have the following:

```
typedef struct _MY_STRUCT
{
   int a;
   float b;
} MY_STRUCT, *PMYSTRUCT
```

What does `*PMYSTRUCT` do?  Is it now a pointer type which I need to declare or just a pointer to `_MY_STRUCT` which I can use?

I know that `MY_STRUCT` is a new type that needs to be used as follows:

```
MY_STRUCT str;
str.a = 2;
```

But what about that `*PMYSTRUCT`?

Comment: This is a common pattern from <windows.h>, a C header by the system implementor (who therefore can use `_MY_STRUCT`). In C++ you don't use typedefs like this, retagged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PMYSTRUCT ms = NULL;
```

is equal to

```
MYSTRUCT* ms = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

It will give the same effect as

typedef MYSTRUCT *  PMYSTRUCT;

It just acts as a typedef to the pointer of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
MY_STRUCT s;
s.a = 10;
PMYSTRUCT ps = &s;
ps->a = 20;
```

Comment: @lalithmohan:  I believe you meant to use
    PMYSTRUCT ps = &s; 
instead of
    MY_STRUCT ps = &s;
Please consider editing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In c, `typedef` has a storage class semantics, just like `static`, `auto` and `extern`.

Consider this:

`static int a, *p;`  - declares a to be a static variable of type **int**, and p to be a static variable of type **pointer to int**.

`typedef int a, *p`  - declares a to be the type **int**, and p to be a type **pointer to int**.